# CoreData Relationship Validation Error handling

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship, nsundomanager, validationerror

I have a one to many relationship between two core data entities.

As Below A->>B

A ->> B : Delete Deny (i.e Deny the deletion of A while their are objects of B)

B -> A : Nullify

In multiple context, one context is unaware of other changes, so in that case i get a validation error while saving the parent context, because in one context a child is inserted to a parent which am deleting in another context.

Their is little to no information provided on how to handle validation error, most of the examples just show error to user and discard the changes. If i need to undo delete of that particular parent object can i?

Is there any option how i can handle the validation error. 
NSValidationRelationshipDeniedDeleteError

Comment: you can still keep track of what is going on in other contexts with `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to undo the delete for only a certain object without losing  changes. So if you have deleted a parent Entity in a `childContext`, then saved the `childContext`, the deleted entity is automatically added to `parentContext.deletedObjects`. I tried different approaches but the only way I was able to cancel the delete operation from the `parentContext` is to call `parentContext.refreshObject(deletedParent, mergeChanges: false)`. (for sure you can try to rollback or reset the context)

It really depends on what you are going to do (so the business has a great influence here!). But I think you should work optimistically: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control
Sometimes, in case of conflicts, it's ok to rollback and restart the transactions.

Usually, the `childContext` overrides the changes of the `parentContext`(the child has higher priority). So the architecture of you app should work the same way. When you delete an entity in the `childContext`, you should also delete it in the `parentContext`, even if the deny rule stops you because you have inserted a new child entity. What you should do is you should remove the inserted entities then delete the parent entity. Otherwise you should restudy the architecture of the app.